# Superkey vs Primary Key

Tags: database, key, relational-database, primary-key

I'm having issues understanding super keys in a relation when the relation only contains one functional dependency.

When considering a relation R(A,B,C,D,E) where A is the primary key and with the functional dependency A->B, can A be considered a super key to the relation since there is only one FD?  Or would one need to expand the functional dependency to include the unmentioned parts of the relation (C,D,E) in order to find a super key?

I'm mainly confused because all the material I've seen on the web until this point has contained multiple functional dependencies all of which have contained all of the attributes within the relation, so I'm not sure how to interpret the unused attributes.  If someone could help clarify this I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only explicitly mentioned FD for the relation schema is A ⟶ B, then there is the implicit, trivial FD {A,B,C,D,E} ⟶ {A,B,C,D,E}.  Given that A ⟶ B, we can deduce that:

- {A,C,D,E} is the primary key of R.
- There is a partial key dependency for A ⟶ B so R is not in BCNF and the relation schema R should be broken down into two non-loss projections:

  - R1(A,B) with A ⟶ B so A is the primary key.
  - R2(A,C,D,E) which is all key (primary key is the combination {A,C,D,E}).
  - And R1 ⋈ R2 ≡ R (assuming ⋈ is the join operation).

As [Catcall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/562459/catcall) says in comments, there is mention of A being the primary key of R.  If A is a primary key, then each of the singleton FDs A  ⟶ B, A ⟶ C, A ⟶ D and A ⟶ E (or, collectively, A ⟶ {B,C,D,E}) applies, and there's no need to call out A ⟶ B separately.  If A is a primary key of R, there's no need to decompose R at all; there is really nothing interesting about the table because it is normalized to 5NF given the available information (assuming there are no unstated non-trivial FDs, MVDs or JDs).

If A is a primary key, then it is also a superkey, but not a proper superkey.  Any of the attribute combinations with A and one or more of the other attributes is also a superkey, and is a proper superkey.

Comment: In the OP's question, it's given that A is the primary key of R.

Comment: If A is a primary key, then A ⟶ {B, C, D, E} by definition of what a primary key means.  However, the only FD given is A ⟶ B.  So, you might be right and then there's just the trivial FD A ⟶ {A,B,C,D,E} and there's no normalization needed.  But there's no interest in that hypothesis.

Comment: "Given that A ⟶ B, we can deduce that: {A,C,D,E} is the primary key of R." No, we can't. If you want to treat {A ⟶ B} as a cover, say so. Don't give "the only explicitly mentioned FD" or the asker's "with the FD A ⟶ B" meanings they don't have. But anyway this first part of the answer has nothing to do with the question, and is just an exercise in vaguely related reasoning that is only going to distract & possibly mislead the asker,  who needs to be disabused of "there is only one FD" & given the definition of "superkey".

Answer (score 1):

> When considering a relation R(A,B,C,D,E) where A is the primary key
>   and with the functional dependency A->B, can A be considered a super
>   key to the relation since there is only one FD?

If it's *given* that A is the primary key of R, then by definition you have the FD A->BCDE. It also follows that

- A->B
- A->C
- A->D
- A->E

If A is a primary key of R, then it follows by definition that A is also a candidate key and a superkey of R.

Answer (score 1):

Lets make it simple:
Here is a definition for **Super,candidate and primary** keys

**Super Keys**

> Super key stands for superset of a key.
>
> A Super Key is a set of one or more attributes that are taken collectively and can identify all other attributes uniquely.

**Candidate Keys**

> Candidate Keys are super keys for which no proper subset is a super key.
>
> In other words candidate keys are minimal super keys.

**Primary Key:**

> It is a candidate key that is chosen by the database designer to identify entities with in an entity set.
>
> Primary key is the **minimal** super keys. In the ER diagram primary key is represented by underlining the primary key attribute.
>
> Ideally a primary key is composed of only a single attribute. But it is possible to have a primary key composed of more than one attribute.

Comment: "Super key stands for superset of a key." Begging the question of what "key" means. And  "key" is never defined. Define superkey correctly either via uniqueness or functionally determining all attributes. This answer has other problems also.